# Using JDBC prepared statement with where clause for Apache Pheonix

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hbase, prepared-statement

I am new to HBase and using Pheonix to query HBase. I am using below query with where condition . It is displaying undefined Column when running this query. Please look into thsi and help me with solution I am using exact column names present in table

```
PreparedStatement     ps = connection.prepareStatement("select * from event_time where name = ? and process = ? and location = ? limit 10");


                ps.setString(1,"myfirstServer");
                ps.setString(2,"1stEvent");
                ps.setString(3,"Chennai");
```

I am getting error undefined column "process" . It is working when I pass only single column name ("select * from event_time where name = ? limit 10")

Comment: It sounds like `event_time` doesn't have a column `process`, or maybe you need to quote it (ie `"process"`, or `"PROCESS"`, etc).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks ..its working with quotes in pheonix jdbc..I dont know what is the significance. I MySQL I have never used quotes for these kind of queries

Comment: It depends: sometimes you need to quote to be able to use reserved words, and some times it is to be able to access case sensitive column names.

Comment: You also need to quote column identifiers if you want it to be case sensitive (ie. if you create the table with quoted identifiers, you need to access it with the same case and quotations)